# How to create a instance of custom class using generics on the fly

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a class definition like this:

```
public class LuRequest<T>
    {
...
    }
```

I want to create a instance of it by assigning the type T dynamically like

```
Type t = OtherObject.GetType();
LuRequest< t>  inst = new LuRequest<t>();
```

However it does not allow me do so, everything in the brackets need to be in compile time.
Is there any way I can do that?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Activator.CreateInstance() method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx

Comment: This is a borderline link-only answer. You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.